# Best library for rendering and zooming SVG

Tags: python, svg, pyqt, rendering, zooming

I've just started to work with python, so I need someone with experience to point me in right direction. I've made a simple GUI using QT-Designer and when I click the button I want it to load and render some test.svg, that I've accomplished using "gtk" and "rsvg". What I also need (after it is rendered) is that zooming and panning is available. Is there some good(better) libs which I should've use for that? If not, which is the best and easiest way for me (noob) to do that?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Qt works very well with SVG. What's the problem?

Comment: @BlaXpirit thank you, I guess I really don't know where to look. So, shortly, those lines does what I want: 'widget = QSvgWidget('C:\someTest.svg') widget.show()' but still I can't zoom or pan rendered svg. There are two more problems: opacity of svg shapes is not rendered, and rendered svg's aspect ratio is not fix(window is stretchable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this using `QGraphicsWebView` instead of `QSvgWidget`. `QGraphicsWebView` already  implements all functionality that internet browsers have, so zooming, panning and scripts in svg work fine.

```
    self.webview = QGraphicsWebView()
    self.webview.resize(SVGwidth,SVGheight)
    self.webview.load(QtCore.QUrl('C:\someTest.svg'))
    self.webview.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemClipsToShape)
    self.webview.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.NoCache)
    self.webview.setZValue(0)
```